# Python Scripts with Blender, Make Human, and Sheepit

Tags: cycles-render-engine, makehuman, sheepit

I am trying to render a project through the online render farm, Sheepit, but it does not allow python scripts. My characters are made in Make Human. I then import it into blender using MHX2. The characters I create in MakeHuman use python scripts. Is there any way to convert the file to make it not need python scripts? This way I can use the online render farm again.

UPDATE:
I have figured out a way to use a MakeHuman model with SheepIt without any issues. Here is a link to my GitHub, where you can find code for the python console and instructions on how to use it: https://github.com/Brody-Adelman/MHX2-Python-Fix

Comment: What exactly do these python scripts do? Not everyone here is familiar with MakeHuman, so any details you can add would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't exactly know what it does. All I know is that without is, the character is severely deformed and won't move correctly. It probably affects the rigging.

Comment: If you have a solution, add an answer rather than editing into  question.  On script: consider setting  `ob = bpy.data.objects[name]`  then refering to it later as `ob`  ... or more blenderifically select it, run script with `ob = context.object`

Answer (score 1):

If the scripts are used to rig the characters - try to bake it. If you want to render physics simulation you have to bake the simulation into keyframes to use the render farm...

Comment: I tried baking the actions and I have no idea if I did it right. All I know is that it didn't work for me. Would you be able to point me towards some sort of tutorial for baking rigs or animations like this?